# Python pandas group by aggregate statement print

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Pandas and I want to use group by statement. it worked but I am enable to print after group by function.
I am using Eclipse IDE
here is my code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                           'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                          'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                'C' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,0,2]})

grouped = df.groupby('C')
print grouped
```

and i get this as ouptut: `<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x02FCA7D0>`

My question is how can i print grouped variable with correct answer

Comment: Please refer to documentation here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always forced it to print using .head()

```
grouped.head()
```

What is happening is you are grouping, but not aggregating the result.

```
grouped = df.groupby('A')
grouped
```

```
grouped_sum = df.groupby('A').sum()
grouped_sum

      C
A      
bar  12
foo  11
```